# PHP using multidimensional arrays with OOP

Tags: php, oop, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

I made a system a while back which involves a basic shopping cart. The cart is a very simple OOP system which adds items by 1 quantity at a time. Here is the function for adding an item to the cart.

```
    function add_item($itemid,$qty=1,$price = FALSE, $info = FALSE)
{ 

    if($this->itemqtys[$itemid] > 0)
            { // the item is already in the cart..
      // so we'll just increase the quantity

        $this->itemqtys[$itemid] = $qty + $this->itemqtys[$itemid];
        $this->_update_total();
    } else {
        $this->items[]=$itemid;
        $this->itemqtys[$itemid] = $qty;
        $this->itemprices[$itemid] = $price;
        $this->iteminfo[$itemid] = $info;
    }
    $this->_update_total();
}
```

The problem with this is some of the products have variations (sizes, colours etc..) but when they chose a different variation in the same order, the products are not added correctly - all of the same product falling under one variation.

I thought it would be an idea to use multidimensional arrays, or arrays within arrays, to produce something like:

```
$this->iteminfo[$itemid][$var];
```

Getting the var from the product is not a problem, just im struggling with how to add the product to the cart with its variation, and updating the quantity of this product/variation combination only when the variation is added again. If a different variation is added, it would add the product in a new entry in the cart?

Hope this makes sense :/ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a single dimension(al) array, but rather than filling it with plain old ints and strings, place a object within it. It will be *much* more robust that way, and you can easily cycle through to get whatever you need - as well as being able to expand the object out further in the future.

Something like this would even work:

```
class itemToBuy
{
    public $itemID;
    public $qty;
    public $price;
    public $info;
    public $whoKnowsWhat;
}

class yourShoppingCart
{
    function add_item($newItem)
    {
        $itemInserted==false;
        $itemsInCart=count($this->itemqtys);
        for($i=0;$i<$itemsInCart;$i++)
        {
            if($this->itemqtys[$i]->itemID==$newItem->itemID)
            {
                $this->itemqtys[$i]->qty+=$newItem->qty;
                $itemInserted=true;
            }
        }
        if(!itemInserted)
        {
            $this->itemqtys[]=$newItem;
        }
        $this->_update_total();
    } 
}
```

Then just pass the object instances of `itemToBuy` rather than the arrays you are passing it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem very OOP to me. You should create a class for the cart items, which holds the quantity, price, variation, etc. and then add objects of this class to you items array in the cart object.

Your method then becomes something along these lines:

```
function add_item($itemid, $qty=1, $variation ="", $price = FALSE, $info = FALSE){ 

    // use itemid concatenated with variation 
    // to get a unique key for every item in your cart 
    if(array_key_exists($itemid . $variation, $this->items)){ 

        // the item is already in the cart..
        // so we'll just increase the quantity
        $item = $this->items[$itemid];

        // this assumes a method in the Item class to add to the quantity
        $item->addToQuantity($qty);

        // put the updated item in the cart
        $this->items[$itemid] = $item;
    } else {
        // create a new item object
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setId($itemid);
        $item->setQuantity($qty);
        $item->setPrice($price);
        $item->setInfo($info);
        $item->setVariation($variation);

        // add it to the items array using a unique key
        $this->items[$itemid . $variation] = $item;
    }
    $this->_update_total();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can a a variation value to the varaiable `$this->itemqtys` for each item and then you can check as follows:

```
<?php
// add a extra $var for checking the variations
function add_item($itemid,$qty=1,$price = FALSE, $info = FALSE, $var=FALSE) {
    if( ( $this->itemqtys[$itemid] > 0 ) && ( $this->itemqtys[$itemid]['var'] == $var ) ) {
          // item already in cart, update
    } else {
          // add item to the cart, along with the variation.
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.